# Looping over db intmap(person)

Tags: opa

example:

```
type person = { name : string
                ; age : int
              }

db /person : intmap(person)
```

I know how to get a single person from the db, but how do I get them all? and print them in a html table?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to use Db.intmap_fold_range instead of InMap.fold.
It will be faster than InMap.fold which need to build the all map in OPA before folding on it.

http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#db.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.db.Db.intmap_fold_range

Here is an example for your type:

```
type person = { name : string
                ; age : int
              }

db /person : intmap(person)

add(name, age) =
  /person[age] <- { ~name; ~age }

fold_person(acc, id) =
 person = /person[id]
 <>{acc}</><li>{person.name} {person.age}</li>

start() =
  do add("name1", 1)
  do add("name2", 2)
  do add("name3", 3)
  Db.intmap_fold_range(
    @/person,
    fold_person,
    <></>, 0, none, /* acc, starting key, optional max */
    (_ -> true) /* check range */
  )

server = one_page_server("Hello", start)
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it :

```
my_html_list() =
  List.map(
    person -> <li>{person.name}</li>,
    IntMap.To.val_list(/person)
  )

render() = <ul>{my_html_list()}</ul>
```

... and then call render() in your server page ...

Comment: I think the body of my_html_list() should be: `IntMap.map(person-><li>{person.name}</li>, /person)` or you should add accumulator if you want to use `IntMap.fold`

Comment: Actually first example works, I get this: "Can't make an xml with ordered_map(int ,xhtml ,Int.order)" on second example

Answer (score 3):

Simply put:

- **/person[i]** gets element i from the database
- **/person** gets the whole intmap from the database
- **!/person** gives you a handle to the database, on which you could use, for example, Db.intmap_fold_range for optimised partial access

Comment: isn't db handle syntax like this @/person ?

Comment: Well, to tell the truth, both **!/person** and **@/person** are handles, with a slight difference:
- with **!/**, the handle refers to a place in the database at the time of binding, in the current transaction.
- with **@/**, you hold a pointer to the database, not bound to any time. This makes more sense e.g. for write operations.

Answer (score 1):

Following @shomodj comment on my answer, this is my complete code to print the persons list (inspired by Cédrics code)

```
// Declare type person
type person = {
  name : string
  age : int
}

// Declare database
db /person : intmap(person)

// Add function
add(name, age) =
  /person[age] <- { ~name ~age }

// Add to database when server launches
do add("name1", 1)
do add("name2", 2)
do add("name3", 3)

// Build the persons <li> list
my_html_list() =
  List.map(
    person -> <li>{person.name}</li>,
    IntMap.To.val_list(/person)
  )

// Build the complete html list (with ul)
render() = <ul>{my_html_list()}</ul>

// Create the server
server = one_page_server("Hello", render)
```

Comment: Note that you can't directly print : <li>{person}</li>

Comment: Sorry I ment your example worked but I could not get @akoprowski comment/example to work.