# Opa: iterate through a database

Tags: database, opa

I've create and populated an opa database, and I'd like to iterate through it's records. How can I do that?

I've created a database as follows:

```
db /files stringmap(binary)
```

Then, I have stored some files in this db:

```
/files[filename1] <- file1
/files[filename2] <- file2
...
```

Now, what I'd like to to is to iterate though the database to get all the couples (filename, file) recorded. (So that I can list them on a webpage)

Is that possible? Or do I have to create another database (for instance an `intmap(string))` to store the filenames using consecutive id, and then use this consecutive ids to get the filenames in the intmap, and from them get the files in the `stringmap(binary)`?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What's the structure of your DB? Do you know how to read DB records? That should pretty much give you enough info to do what you want, right?

Comment: My database is a stringmap(binary), i.e. I store files. What I want to do is to get all the couples (filename : string, file : binary) stored in this db. I know how to access a file knowing it's name, but I don't know how to get all the filenames stored in the db. Thanks

Comment: I found the answer to my question here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649823/looping-over-db-intmapperson

Comment: Indeed. In the spirit of StackOverflow, I suggest that you put your comment as an answer and then accept it (for future users looking for an answer; it's much better visible this way than buried in the comments)

Comment: I found the answer to my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649823/looping-over-db-intmapperson